# Illegal start of type in math test

Tags: java

I'm just messing around with the few things I have learnt and I decided to try and make a math test. The test asks you the question and then gives you an entry box to answer it in.

My problem is when trying to compile I get the error "illegal start of type" for the if statement. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class mathtest {
    public static void main(String[] args);{
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("What is 5 + 5 ?");
        double y = x.nextDouble();
    }
    if (y == 10) {
        System.out.println("Correct");
    } else
        System.out.println("Incorrect");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't worry about it being a beginner post, a skill or knowledge requirement is non-existent. The only thing is, remember to always show some effort in trying to fix your bug or error before answering the question, and tell us what you've tried. Don't be vague, either. These things will earn you downvotes. Not that you did either of those in this question, though. :)

Comment: thank you, I will try and bear it in mind in future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
 public static void main(String[] args);{ // remove the ;
```

Comment: You also need to delete the "}" immediately before the if-statement. It ends the main method, leaving the if outside any block. I strongly recommend using an editor with automatic indentation, and letting it format your code.

Comment: Also, when you say automatic indentation, do you mean it will automatically add correct brackets?

Comment: @user2992500 No, it will indent according to your brackets. However, bracket errors are very visible, and easy to correct, if the code is indented properly.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `;` between `main` and `{`.

```
class mathtest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `x.nextDouble()`?

Comment: woops, yes, stupid me changing the variable names.. this was not causing the problem however

Comment: public static  void main(String[] args)      { 


       Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

             System.out.println("What is 5 + 5 ?");
             double y = x.nextDouble();

             if (y == 10) {
                  System.out.println("Correct");
              }
              else 
                  System.out.println("Incorrect");
              } 

Works for me

Answer (score 0):

don't use `;` remove it

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `x.nextDouble();`, should it not?
And your problem lies in the `main` method. Remove the semicolon, so it looks like this: 
`public static void main(String[] args) {`

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with the code .

1. No ; is required after declaring a method.
2. There is no variable a declared anywhere in the code
3. A variable declared inside a method is only visible inside the scope of the method. You have declared y inside main and used it outside .
4. there is an extra } at the end.